# How to change the units for storage size from GiB/MiB to GB/MB (binary prefix)?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, system-settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to switch Ubuntu back to base-2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110999/is-it-possible-to-switch-ubuntu-back-to-base-2)

Since a while ago, Ubuntu has adopted the policy of requiring decimal and binary prefixes to follow the relevant standards. That's great, and it clears a lot of confusion as to which prefixes are being used.

One of the side effects of this policy seems to be that the decimal prefixes are now used in most of the places by default, such as in nautilus. I find this quite confusing, mainly because the command line tools such as du etc still use the binary prefixes, so one gets different size figures when using different tools (of course it is easy to tell which one is being used by looking at the number of bytes without the prefix, but it is annoying one is having to do that). I would very much like to switch to using the binary prefixes at least in nautilus, but cannot seem to find an option for doing so.

So to my question. Does anybody know how to change the prefixes being used in Nautilus? Bonus kudos for a GNOME system-wide method.