# How to change file size calculation in Nautilus from "decimal prefix" back to the normal "binary prefix"?

Tags: nautilus

Ubuntu has used the "base-10" [Units Policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy) for almost 3 years now, and being a full Ubuntu user from the awesome 10.10, personally I never was able to relate with it!

I'm not going to talk about how right/wrong this decision was in my opinion and many other Ubuntu users. Instead my question is if there is a clean solution to make the whole system or at least Nautilus use the "base-2" or "binary-prefix"?

I've seen [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110999/), which the answer states that there is no solution to this problem (unless modifying the entire source of Ubuntu!!) but that post is old and for the times of Ubuntu-11.10. I was wondering if there has been any changes since then?

Not to mention that another post in that question states that KDE is able to do this in the System Settings! If this is true, why not also put an option in Unity ?!

I'm mostly an LTS user, currently using Ubuntu-12.04 (and looking forward to 14.04). If there isn't a way to configure the whole system to use the "binary-prefix", can I at least configure Nautilus to do this?

Comment: No updates on this, this ship sailed a long time ago.

Comment: Really a shame to hear that ... Taking a look on the Internet, and  the up-votes for this and similar questions, it is clear that this issue needs to be addressed by Canonical.