# How to change "Units Policy" in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, files, policy

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 and *Nautilus* ("Files") for file management. I am accustomed to file sizes reported in multiple of 1024. However, Nautilus displays files size in multiple of 1000.

For, example, a file with size of 367,165,440 bytes is displayed as having size `367.2 MB` in Nautilus. However, I want Nautilus to display the size as `350.2 MB` (= 367,165,440 ÷ 1024 ÷ 1024). Is there a hidden option to change the "[Units Policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy)" from 1000 to 1024 in Nautilus?

Comment: i personally use `nemo` for file management, and it also uses 1000 as `Units policy`. Could it be related to Ubuntu itself rather then the file manager ?

Comment: i've checked out and it is Ubuntu related. They switched to the base-10 `metric system` (called `SI standard`) since Ubuntu 10.10 instead of the `IEC standard` wich is base-2 and simply perfect for binary measuring.

Comment: Here is an old thread about the same issue (Ubuntu 10.10) : https://askubuntu.com/questions/110999/is-it-possible-to-switch-ubuntu-back-to-base-2

Comment: Poor **me** and **Bob** (mentioned in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy)! :(

Comment: you can change the `Unit Policy` in `nemo` by editing it preferences. Hoped it could also change it in `Nautilus` but it don't.

Comment: `Thunar` also works as I expect. But, I am not using it too much.